# Android SDK Manager.exe does not work

Tags: java, android

i just stated develponog for android and i dont really know what is happening.
when i open the SDK Manager.exe application everything opens fine exept for when i try to type into the command line section of it does not work. also i have looked everywhere to find out why i need to setup a path for the SDK. does this have to do with the SDK manager?
i am running it on a netbook

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Have you already installed **Java SE Development Toolkit 1.6**? If so, perhaps you already had an older **JDK** installed and when you try to run `SDK Manager.exe` it first fetchs the older one. There are two possible solutions:

- Rollback your JDK instalations, and when you have no JDK present in your netbook, then install the 1.6 version.

OR

- Go to `Control Panel` -> `System` -> `Advanced` -> `Environment Variables`

In system variables look for `Path` variable and click `Edit`. Check if the value field doesn't have the path to your Java JDK’s bin folder. If that already exists substitute to the correct one. (ie `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin`). Otherwise, you need to insert this path at the front of the list. Insert the path followed by a `;`. Click ok all the way and reboot your machine.

After this, give another chance to `SDK Manager.exe`! :)